# Any way to make all objects to have the same colour in Dwarf Fortress regardless of their material?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

[Graphics set is used] Is there any existing solution to make all objects of the same kind to have the same colour regardless of their material? I.e. I don't want all beds and other furniture to look differently on screen depending on their material. The same partly applies to the environment, eg. I'd like all clay floor tiles to look the same, all grass the same, etc. While leaving ore/gems coloured.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the raw file for the materials, and there change the colour of the materials to be all the same.

Comment: It may be helpful to give specifics on how to do this

Comment: https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Raw_file